# jQuery .on() method doesn't see new elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, click, jquery-events

I'm getting a JSON element and building a list from its items like this:

```
getTitles: function(data) {
    data = data || {};
    var list = [];

    $.getJSON(
        '/titles',
        data,
        function(data) {
            $.each(data.data, function(key, val) {
                list.push(
                    '<li><a href="'+ val.href +'">'+ val.title +'</a><span class="count">'+ val.count +'</span></li>'
                )
            });

            $('#title-items').html(list.join(''));
        }
    );
}
```

And I'm binding click event for `a` elements like this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Old `a` elements shows alert but new ones follow URL. Event handler doesn't work for new ones. How can I solve this?

Comment: From the [jQuery doco for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/): "Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 146, accepted):

You are not using the correct code to get *live* functionality.

```
$('#title-items').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

1. First, select your common ancestor element (`#title-items` in this example). You can use `document` here too if you want to handle *all* `a` elements.
2. Pass the event type (`on`), *then* the sub selector (`a`), and then the callback function for the event.

Now, when `click` events bubble up to `#title-items`, it will check to see if the element is an `a` element, and if so, fire the callback.

Comment: @cnkt: Use `document` for your common ancestor element.

Comment: @cnkt: You have to use jQuery >= 1.7 to use `.on()`.

Comment: @alex is this very unpractical? I mean, if I attached this event on the document, then it will triggers this function on every click as you said. :?:?:?

Comment: @gotqn I think you could probably restrict this a little bit so it doesn't attach to every anchor using the <li> ... `$('#title-items').on('click', 'li a', function(e) { alert('clicked'); e.preventDefault(); });`

Answer (score 14):

You want to use event delegation to capture events triggered on events that are present in the DOM at any point in time:

```
$(<root element>).on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**UPDATE** - In this example the `<root element>` is an ancestor of the links to which you are binding that is present in the DOM at the time of binding.

The basic idea is that since we can't attach an event handler to a DOM element not yet in the DOM, we attach the event handler to an ancestor element and wait for the event to bubble up to the ancestor element. Once the event reaches the ancestor event the `event.target` property is checked to see what was the originally clicked element.

Comment: @Gabe I don't have any idea what the user's HTML structure looks like so this is a demonstration of the general idea. Also `.live()` is depreciated, so I wouldn't use it in an example.

Comment: @Jasper: `live()` was never really appreciated! I think you mean *deprecated* :P

Comment: @Gabe Doesn't that depend on how nested the elements are?

Comment: @Jasper, yes it would depend on how it's nested, I will remove the downvote, if you edit your answer, since it won't let me until do you do... I just think that could potentially lead to bad practice with this example. The other answer demonstrated a better practice.

Comment: @Gabe That's a good idea, I went more generic than the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [arrive.js](https://github.com/uzairfarooq/arrive/) library (it uses [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) internally).

```
document.arrive('a', function(){
    // 'this' refers to the newly created element
    var newElem = this;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the accepted answer, note that if you'll use `a` as a jQuery object vs a `string` - if you'll make a mistake in the jQuery selector - the event will always be fired when `#title-items` is clicked ( no matter of `a` / `p` etc .. )

```
var a_links1 = $('a');
var a_links2 = $('bla');

$('#title-items').on('click', a_links1, function(e) {
    alert('clicked');   <= fire only on <a> elements
});

$('#title-items').on('click', a_links2, function(e) {
    alert('clicked');   <= fire on every element under <#title-items>
});
```

That is unless you'll use strings

```
$('#title-items').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');   <= fire only on <a> elements
});

$('#title-items').on('click', 'bla', function(e) {
    alert('clicked');   <= won't fire at all, as the selector won't match anything
});
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7f8y5ak6/1/

It is important to understand that, because when you're expecting `$('bla')` to be added in the future ( or after some click ) - but you loaded the bind event before that - jQuery's selector won't "find"/"see" them - then you're expected this behavior when everything is clickable.

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me https://www.learningjquery.com/2017/02/jquery-on-method-the-issue-of-dynamically-added-elements

**jQuery .on() method used as direct event will not work for dynamically added elements. Use delegate event via passing the selector parameter so that container takes the responsibility of executing the event in case of elements added in future dynamically.**

You can keep .on inside or outside of `$(document).ready` both logs will work!

For custom tag

```
$(document).on("click","[mycustomtag]", function(){
    console.log("Clicked.");
});
```

for HTML classes or id's etc

```
$(document).on("click","div", function(){
    console.log("Clicked.");
});
```